# webpack produces inconsistent results with packages installed using pnpm link

Tags: node.js, webpack, pnpm

I have a node project and an npm package that's used in that project. I need to produce a source code archive that anyone else can use to build the project and get the same exact result as me. I can't give away access to the npm registry where the package is hosted, so I'm bundling the package source code with the project. However, when I build the package and link it using `pnpm link <path to pkg dir>` (and `pnpm install <path to pkg dir>` too, but the result was the same), the output that webpack produces is different than when the package is installed from the registry. I checked and the build of the package itself is identical to the private npm registry, so something must be wrong with the project itself.

I also tried downloading the package from the registry using `npm pack` and installing it using `pnpm install <path to pkg archive>` and the output was different again. It seems like no matter what the package content is, something changes with the way of installation of the package and that messes the build up.

Any ideas?